# Print the line one above of a line in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file and it includes over 8000 lines. I need to print one specific line and also print another line which is  one previous line of first one. The problem is the second line has no uniqe feature so I cannot call it as I call the first one.

Sum up

:

-- Second Line

-- First Line

:

How do I get Second line by using first line ?

I know that I should counter lines and capture the second line but I dont know how. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Print?  As in to a printer, or to a file?  Show your attempted code.

Comment: _I know that I should_ Says who? Homework?

Comment: How do you determine the "one specific line" that you need to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a .txt file with a bunch of lines and buried in the middle are two lines with "Frank" on the first and "Ball" on the second.  To print "Frank Ball" try this:

```
string line;
        string line1;
        string line2;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
        //walk the file line by line
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if(line.Contains("Ball"))
            {
                //Once you find your search value, set line2 to the line and stop walking the file.
                line2 = line;
                break;
            }
            //set line1 to the line value to hold onto it if you find your search value

            line1 = line;
        }
       //Now you have both strings and you can concatenate them however you want and print them
        string s = line1 + " " + line2;

        PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
        p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
        {
            e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

        };
        try
        {
            p.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
        }

        file.Close();
```

Comment: That's hilarious. I wouldn't have jumped to the GDI to "print" something, but I guess it works. :)

Comment: It's fast, simple and pretty much bulletproof.

Comment: Yeah - I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string GetPreviousLine(string[] lines)
{
    string temp = "";
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line == "First Line") return temp;
        else temp = line;
    }
    throw new Exception("not found");
}
```

We read each line and save it to `temp`. Then we read the next line, and if it's `line 1`, we know that `temp` is `line 2`, else we save the new line to `temp` and continue in the same manner.

Comment: @3Dave Where do I pass an array by value?

Comment: @3Dave Wrong. This is exactly like `List<string>`. Both are passed by reference.

Comment: My bad. Never mind.

Comment: I've been in C++ land for quite awhile; shifting back and forth is sometimes troublesome.

Comment: @3Dave I was going to comment that, but your profile showed C# as the highest tag. I guess C++ does cause confusion after all :)

Comment: Try shifting back and forth between templates and generics. It goes from frustrated at c++ (object slicing) and pissed off at C# limitations. I'm happiest in whichever I've been working in for the most recent few days.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I should counter lines and capture the second line but I dont know how.

To count the lines, you can simply use a `for` loop on the `lines` array returned by the method `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)`. This will increment on each iteration, and you can access the previous line by using `lines[i - 1]`.

Here's a method that will search through a string array using a `for` loop, looking for a line that matches the specific string (case-insensitive in this example) and return the previous array item if the search term is found:

```
private static string GetLineBefore(string lineToFind, string[] lines)
{
    // Argument validation to avoid NullReferenceException or unnecessary search
    if (lines != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineToFind))
    {
        // Start at the second line (index 1) since there is no line before the first
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Equals(lineToFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // Since 'i' represents the index of the first line that we were
                // searching for, we return the previous item, at index 'i - 1'
                return lines[i - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    // If we never found our first line, return null to indicate no results
    return null;
}
```

You could call it like:

```
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";
var searchLine = "This is the text for the first line that I want to find";

// This will represent the line before the first one above
var previousLine = GetLineBefore(searchLine, File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
```